# How do I change the color of Eclipse's title bar?

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed the "Darkest Dark Theme" for Eclipse, which uses DevStyle. It works great, except the title bar at the top of the window is bright white.

[Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwUR0.png)

How can I change the color of Eclipse's title bar in Windows?

Comment: Didn't you notice any issue or any slowdown after installing DevStyle or do you just not mind the measurable slowdown and the issues? In the upcoming [Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) the menu will become dark in the dark theme](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#dark-win32-menu), but the window title will be still rendered by the operating system and must be changed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your windows theme.
This part of the window is under windows responsibility and not the program.

[Instruction to change to dark theme](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/04/01/windows-10-tip-dark-theme-in-file-explorer/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is any theme available for that feature in eclipse as most themes focus on the menubar and coding area look&feel. Try changing your windows theme if necessary.